# How to send ethernet frames from one veth to another?

Tags: network-interface, network-namespaces, virtual-interface

I have two veth pairs (veth1, veth1_0) and (veth2, veth2_0). veth1_0 and veth2_0 are in the default namespace ns0, veth1 is in namespace ns1 and veth2 in namespace ns2. I want to communicate between different namespaces. So I use veth1_0 to send an ethernet frame to veth2_0(use pcap_sendpacket), hoping I can capture the packet at veth2. And in my output, I can capture the packet in namespace 1 at veth1; but fail to do in namespace 2 at veth2. I wonder if it's possible to accomplish the communication in this way; or maybe there are other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but the normal approach is to create a bridge in the main namespace, and just make `veth1_0` and `veth2_0` members of the bridge.

Then you given `veth1` and `veth2` proper IP addresses in their respective namespaces, add routing if necessary, let the IP stack do its thing and stop worrying about ethernet packets. In particular, don't use anything like pcap.